# Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04, end of life version

Tags: upgrade, 18.10, do-release-upgrade

I am facing this issue when attempting an upgrade to ubuntu 19.04.

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Apparently my release is not supported anymore... which doesn't allow me to upgrade. Seems like I am stuck.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 has reached EOL (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/) thus mirrors could have dropped it.  My own used mirror still has it (I just looked) so you could try switching to the main archive, or look for another (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors), or switch to old-releases.ubuntu.com then `apt update; apt full-upgrade`, `then do-release-upgrade`

Answer (score 3):

The fault lay in `Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.` 
A package was held back and it was stopping the upgrade. I updated the held package and got it unstuck.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of your resolution. This worked for me!